# How to run c# code from python *In the same process*?

Tags: c#, python, bridge

I want to run some c# function from python.

I know this can be done with

```
os.system("myapp.exe")
```

and other similar calls, but this would create a new process.

I would like to have the c# code run from the same process which is running the python code.

How can this be done?

---

One way I thought of is compiling the c# to dll, and calling its functions from there, but I still haven't been able to make this way work.

Is there a better way?

Comment: That is impossible. An application can have one process. In your case, the process is the Python interpreter. You can not run another application within the same process.

Comment: @RayWu Please see the edit. why would it be impossible?

Comment: One process can only have one application. 

Besides, Python can only directly call unmanaged DLLs, that is, DLLs written in C or C++.

Comment: What is your use case? I'm suspecting this may be an XY problem.

Comment: @RayWu My main project is written in python. We had some contractor provide c# code we don't want to rewrite in python. We need to integrate the c# code (with maybe a few API changes) into the main project. I suggested calling the c# .exe from python, and communicating with it through a file or a socket, but concerns have been raised about having to manage a subprocess, and having maintenance overhead and extra bugs by the extra process, so I am trying to find alternatives

Comment: You might be able to load the .NET runtime in python by calling an unmanaged dll and load your managed dll from there, but that sounds like a lot of work and equally prone to bugs and problems

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NuGet package [`UnmanagedExports`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) for this.<sup>1</sup>
For Python `ctypes` compatible code, you need to add the attribute
`[DllExport("<function name>", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`

There is no way of doing this without modifying the C# assembly.

---

From Python code:

```py
import ctypes
a = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(<path to dll>)
```

You can now use the object `a` to call methods in the C# assembly that have been prefixed with the `DllExport` Attribute.

---

Information taken from [the official website of UnmanagedExports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports).

---

<sup>[1] You can always use COM, however, this is much harder to do, and involves 
 much more restructuring of the C# assembly.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Is the use of a different interpreter all together on the table for consideration?
You could use [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/), which would allow you to import a dll as you would a normal python package, and embed your C# classes into your python script.

```py
clr.AddReference('mylib.dll') # contains namespace MyLib
import MyLib
```

Comment: This answer only works if the OP is not using any external Python modules that contain C extensions (highly unlikely for larger projects). Perhaps this should be edited into the answer.